# I wonder why do we have only four candidates for moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderation, moderators

I wonder why do we have only four candidates for moderator election?

Did I miss the time where we had more candidates?

Did every influencing contributors who wanted to be moderator win the previous election?

Comment: Just for reference for (current) 2019 election: there are [626 users](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/1017720) who were eligible to nominate, and who have accessed the site (not necessary the election page) since the election started. Out of them, we don't know how many have accessed the election page at least once. Also, some users (and mostly low-rep users) are probably not even this site's regulars, or just focusing on Q&A aspect, not the moderation part (because moderation tools are rep-based privileges)

Answer (score 5):

From the last Moderator Election I don't remember there being larger numbers of candidates. I think that this is still a site with a relatively small base of regular contributors which makes the pool of members who feel they have the experience to take it on fairly small. In fact checking back the last election only had 4 candidates too. I think it is more a case of needing to grow the active community engagement to help boost overall users numbers before we expect much more to happen on the elections.

I did think of putting myself forward but felt at the moment that I still have too many work commitments to do it justice as well as too light a skill set on the Apex and Lightning development side and I think I am probably not alone in that feeling.